# Determining number of calls (activations) to mergesort

Tags: algorithm, big-o, mergesort

I'm studying for a CS 125 final exam, and Big O Notation was covered (briefly).

Given that:

- Mergesort has a Running Time Best Case of O(N lg(N)) and Running Time Worst Case of O(N lg (N))
- There are 32 floating point values, initially in random order, stored in a double array

How many total calls(activations) to mergesort will there be if the array is to be sorted? Assume the base case sorts a single value.

I would go ahead and say simply plug in 32 to the worst case or best case (as mergesort guarantees O(N lg (N)).

This does not give me the correct solution (which is apparently 31). Can someone provide some pointers or an explanation? I just don't see it.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with big-O or running time. What's the definition of mergesort? Can you come up with a recurrence relation for the number of mergesort calls for an array of size 2^k?

Comment: Big O is about asymptotic boundaries, not about exact numbers. If you need to determine how often a function is called, take a specific input and the code of your implementation, then start counting.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. If the base case sorts a single element, there will be at minimum 32 calls to mergesort, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 32 is 2<sup>5</sup>, the recursion tree will be a full binary tree. We then do 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 63 calls to mergesort. It is unclear to me why the answer would be 31, when they state the base case is length 1. Apparently they don't count the last level of recursion (or they assume you don't recurse when the length is 1).

In your original attempt, you are confusing running time with recursive calls. Mergesort's O(n log n) is an upper bound on the number of *comparisons between elements* the algorithm makes. As we want to count the number of recursive calls, knowing this bound doesn't do us any good (although knowing how the algorithm *works* does).

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. They are most likely considering an implementation where input of two elements is simply sorted instead of having a redundant recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the solid explanation -- this topic was briefly covered and I wasn't even sure how to approach the problem because we've never done anything like it.

Comment: I would personally argue 63 as well -- your logic seems to make more sense, and they didn't state that we are supposed to exclude the last level. Perhaps a mistake was made in the problem set

Answer (score 0):

So, mergeSort method does the splitting job and merge method does the conquering job.

For a list size of 32, I think, there are 63 mergeSort calls, which is 2 * 32 - 1 = 63. And there are 31 merge calls, which is 32 - 1 = 31.