# Mergesort - maximum number of recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, mergesort

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30164779/1483663) there was an example with calculating the number of mergesort recursion calls for an array of length 32 (worst case): 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 63.

It's pretty trivial to imagine why it's the case - on every level of the tree we have power-of-2 nodes and we always go to the next level till the last one.

I wonder how to calculate this number (maximum number of recursion calls) for an array of arbitrary length `n`? In practice, the number seems to be `2*n-1` but I can't understand why. Can someone explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see the pattern.

If `n = 1` there is a single call (that has nothing to do).

If it is true for `n` then for `2n` our first call divides it into `n` and `n`, each of which we sort in `2n-1` calls, for `4n-2` more.  So we need `1 + 4n-2 = 4n - 1 = 2*(2n)-1` and the result holds.

If it is true for `n` and `n+1` then for `2n+1` our first call divides it into `n` and `n+1`.  We sort those with another `2n-1` and `2(n+1)-1 = 2n+1` calls.  Making for `1 + 2n-1 + 2n+1 = 4n + 1 = 2*(2n+1) - 1` calls.

So because it is true for 1, it is true for 2.  Because it is true for 1 and 2 it is true for 3.  Because it is true for 2 it is true for 4.  Because it is true for 2 and 3 it is true for 5.  And so on.

You can easily turn this around and make it into a formal proof by strong induction.